# Not able to run cronjob (.sh file) having RAILS bundle command in linux

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-3, cron

I have scheduled a cronjob to run `sche.sh` file daily. That sh file has the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

I am receiving an exception at this line stating that

> bundle command not found

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed bundler?

```
$ gem install bundler
```